# Having trouble using HDD alongside SSD on arch linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, arch-linux

## Cant use both my hard drives on my new setup

### Backround Info

I recently switched from a windows setup to arch linux as the title suggests, I have backed up most of my important things on an external hard drive of 1TB, now my main issue is that i dont understand how handling more than one hardrive in linux works, I had no problem partitioning and setting up my SSD to run my OS on, I have 3 partitions on my SSD nvme0n1p1 which is my EFI partition, nvme0n1p2 which is my SWAP and nvme0n1p3 which is my linux-filesystem which is ~250gb.

### What i wish to achieve

Now i also have a 1TB HDD which i didnt setup in the initial installing process but i would like to utilize to store things like large files, VMs, games, tools(i want to install the blackarch repo there) but i am facing difficulties utilizing it.

### Current system

For starters to give some background im running normal arch with just a WM (xmonad), ive tried alot of things and have asked for help from many people to basically no avail, the closest i got to functionality was making a ext4 file system with fdisk and mounting it on a directory i called /HDD and putting a VM on there, but it got really annoying because to access anything on that drive you needed root privileges meaning i had to run virtualbox with sudo, additionally i couldnt get pacman to install software there instead of my SSD, i want to be able to have control of what goes where in my system, meaning that at any given time I'd like to be able to store stuff on my SSD or my HDD and have good control over both of them without it being a hassle.

### Attempts to solve my issue

I tried LVM as someone suggested in the arch linux discord following a video by Chris Titus Tech but i got stuck due to the fact there is no existing volume group nor will it let me create one, also while looking through different ways to solve the issue we went over the scenario of backing everything up and re partitioning my drives to make a volume group when we realized that i also cant use my external drive since i also cant figure out how to get that working on my system without deleting all the files inside of it since it has all my important backups from windows.

### Summary

I dont know what to do but to summarize i want to have control over my 2 hard drives and be able to easily switch between saving data and programs on one drive or the other as well as getting my external hard drive to function without loosing my saved data. I know this is alot but I have been searching for hours to no avail.

Comment: Excuse me, but I'm not going to read this unformatted wall of text. Please organize it into paragraphs and use formatting where it makes sense. The easier it is to read, the more eager people will be to read it. It's in your best interest.

Comment: How were you using the HDD before? or is it new

Comment: Ok @gronostaj i reformatted the question to be a little bit more comprehensive, now is there any way you can help me?

Comment: @user253751 When i was still using windows i used it to store games VMs and big files but I deleted everything when switching OS obv

Comment: I understand that you want to get back some files that were present on this HDD? With which filesystem is it formatted? I don't specifically know about Arch Linux, but more generally under a Linux OS, if a drive doesn't mount automatically, then you have to manually add an entry in the `/etc/fstab` file

Comment: @SpiliosMaderakis I mean did it show up as a separate disk or did it somehow merge with your main disk?

Comment: @PierU sorry for the confusing but no, I have an HDD which i want to use on my system as well as a third external drive with files in it, which uses one of the four windows file systems, not sure which one

Answer (score 1):

> the closest i got to functionality was making a ext4 file system with fdisk and mounting it on a directory i called /HDD and putting a VM on there, but it got really annoying because to access anything on that drive you needed root privileges

The reason you need root privileges is because the filesystem's *file permissions* say so, not because of fdisk or /HDD. The default for freshly created filesystems is to make the disk's toplevel directory owned by "root:root" with the usual 0755 permissions – use `chmod` and/or `chown` to change this.

(Note that the disk must be mounted at the time of chmod/chown, i.e. "/HDD" must refer to the mounted disk and not to the empty mountpoint directory underneath.)

> additionally i couldnt get pacman to install software there instead of my SSD

You won't be able to change this easily – the Linux file structure, where files are organized by purpose rather than by package, means that many programs will expect to find their files at specific locations (e.g. /usr/lib/ for libraries and plugins rather than /HDD/usr/lib). Some such paths may be changed using environment variables (like appending /HDD/usr/bin to $PATH), but many others cannot (they're set at compile time), so pacman doesn't even try to offer the option to relocate specific packages.

Some other distributions may allow this more easily (e.g. possibly Nix?).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i will change the privileges of the HDD to at least make it a bit more useful, however I am facing an issue, that is the black arch repo is apparently "too large" for my SSD and it wont download despite it having like 200gb of free space which the black arch repo isint that large, but is there any way that i cn make all programs from pacman installed on my HDD or should i give up on that dream and focus on how to fix blackarch downloading on my SSD